# Delete multitable HSQLDB

Tags: sql, hsqldb, sql-delete, multi-table-delete

Are the multitable DELETE statements supported by HSQLDB?

I've done some searches on Google and in the forum, but can't find a topic that deals with this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not directly as of version 2.2.5.

But you can write a stored procedure to delete from multiple tables according to some criteria, then call the procedure with the necessary parameters. See the Guide:

http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/sqlroutines-chapt.html

Comment: Can you give me a sample code of your solution? Also, on another post i've found this solution DELETE FROM T1 WHERE T1.C1 IN (SELECT T2.C2 FROM T2 WHERE <condition>)
What do you think on it? Thanks

Comment: In the previous comment, i delete rows from T1 according to a condition on T2. That's exactly what I wanted to do.

Comment: I wrote the other answer. If you use ON DELETE CASCADE, then it is a solution for you.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see the username. Thanks for your answers.